# Programmatically closing an NSWindow when it loses focus

Tags: cocoa, macos, nswindow

I am making an image picker that will display an n by n grid of selectable button when the picker is popped up.  This grid of buttons will be contained within an NSWindow but I would like for the window to be close automatically if the user clicks off the screen.  Is there a flag that can be set so that when the window looses focus it will be closed automatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two notifications that you may be interested in: `NSWindowDidResignKeyNotification` and `NSWindowDidResignMainNotification`.  You can simply register for the one you're interested in in awakeFromNib (or windowDidLoad if you have a custom controller) and then close or hide the window as appropriate when you receive the notifications.

I won't delve too much into whether or not this is a good idea from  UI standpoint. But, it might be a better idea to have either an overlay view or a panel for the functionality you describe.

Answer (score 5):

You might check out [NSPanel](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It's an NSWindow subclass that will hide itself when the app is in the background, and that behavior sounds very similar to what you are looking for.

Comment: The question is about closing the window when the **window** looses focus, though. `NSPanel` hides when the **app** looses focus.