# Mac Menu Bar Tutorial?

Tags: macos, menu

I have seen many apps in the Mac App Store that are simple apps that shows you the mobile version of FaceBook or Google Reader in the menu bar.

I am not sure where to start though, so I'm asking you guys.

I would like the app to display a mobile version of FaceBook in a dropdown style window (coming from the menu bar) when the toolbar icon is pressed. Any links on how to get started will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think NSStatusItem is what you're looking for.

Check the following tutorial:
[Creating a Standalone StatusItem Menu](http://www.sonsothunder.com/devres/livecode/tutorials/StatusMenu.html)

Another nice example project:
[Using MAAttachedWindow with an NSStatusItem](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/03/04/using-maattachedwindow-with-an-nsstatusitem)

Comment: Okay so the second example is more of what I want, however the tooltip won't be the frontmost window and won't close when unclicked. I read that this will solve that problem `[window setLevel:NSMainMenuWindowLevel];` but I'm not sure where to put it. I can provide the source code if you'd like.

Comment: Open `AppController.m` and add `[attachedWindow setLevel:NSMainMenuWindowLevel];` right above `[attachedWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];`.

Comment: Okay, that's working. However it was still showing below some so I changed it to `NSMainMenuWindowLevel +100` and it showed above all others. Is this the best way to do it?

Comment: You might consider using `NSStatusWindowLevel`.

Comment: Will any of those close the window when something else is clicked, like a different menu icon or the desktop?

Comment: Check: [Programmatically closing an NSWindow when it loses focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950067/programmatically-closing-an-nswindow-when-it-loses-focus)

Comment: Okay I checked that out and searched google for a guide but found nothing. Instead I'm working on making the "3" and image. I changed the `(void)drawRect` to what this user was saying http://mattgemmell.com/2008/03/04/using-maattachedwindow-with-an-nsstatusitem/comment-page-1#comment-46501 however I get multiple errors such as "Expected )" or "stray \342".